# What happens when Index creation in MongoDB which is running in background fails

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

There are existing collections in MongoDB on which need to be programmatically updated for new indexes.
So there is an admin web API in my ASP.net application when invoked will invoke the create index API in MongoDB. In order to not cause an impact due to index building process, it is performed in background.

It is not known whether the existing data is good as per the index definition. Because Mongo DB imposes index key size limit to 1024, and it may be possible that values of indexed fields in some of the existing documents may sum up to length more than 1024.

So the question is when this happens what would happen when the index building fails due to this.
Also how can I programmatically (C# driver) find the status of the index build operation at a later point in time?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/index.html#Index-Key-Limit)

> MongoDB will not create an index on a collection if the index entry for an existing document exceeds the index key limit. Previous versions of MongoDB would create the index but not index such documents.

So this means, background or foreground, an index key too long will cause the creation to fail. However, no matter how you create the index, the [session issuing the create index command, will block.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/#background-construction) This means if the index build fails, you should be notified by an exception thrown while `await`-ing the task returned by the `Indexes.CreateManyASync()` method.

Since you are unsure if the data will be affected by the maximum key length, I strongly suggest you test this in a pre-production environment before attempting it in production. Since production is (I assume) active, the pre-production environment won't match the data exactly (writes still happening) it will reduce the possibility of finding a failed index build in production.

Additionally, even if the index is able to be built, in the future, writes that break that key length will be rejected. This can be avoided by setting [failIndexKeyTooLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.failIndexKeyTooLong) server parameter. However this has its own set of caveats. Specifically,

> Setting failIndexKeyTooLong to false is a temporary workaround, not a permanent solution to the problem of oversized index keys. With failIndexKeyTooLong set to false, queries can return incomplete results if they use indexes that skip over documents whose indexed fields exceed the Index Key Length Limit.

I strongly suggest you read and understand those docs before implementing that particular parameter.

In general, it is considered by many to be bad practice to build an index at run-time. If the collection is already empty, this is not a big deal, however on a collection with a large amount of data, this can cause the create command to block for quite some time. This is especially true on a busy `mongod` when creating the index in the background.

If you are building this index on a Replica Set or Sharded Cluster, I strongly recommend you take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/#build-indexes-on-replica-sets-and-sharded-clusters) specific to those use cases before implementing the build in code.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It is helpful. so if I understand correctly, the .net driver would block until the background index creation is successful/failure and then if there is any index key limit violation, then the index would fail to create. As a result, the .net driver API will fail. This makes sense.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `await` on the command to create the index would block, but the whole driver doesn't block. In a multi-threaded application (like an ASP.NET application), other requests would still be processed by the driver, even ones on that collection.